# ERROR: meson setup failed

Tags: emulation

i am new to linux, Currently i'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Im trying to emulate an ipod touch 1g. i was following this tutorial: https://devos50.github.io/blog/2022/ipod-touch-qemu-pt2. Everything was going well until i got to the step to configure qemu. i got a meson error. i was wondering if anyone could help me out. Thank you. btw Here is the log:

```
Build started at 2023-06-03T22:43:58.295304
Main binary: /usr/bin/python3
Build Options: -Daudio_drv_list=default -Ddefault_devices=true -Ddocdir=/usr/local/share/doc -Dqemu_firmwarepath=/usr/local/share/qemu-firmware -Dqemu_suffix=qemu -Dsphinx_build= -Dtrace_file=trace -Doptimization=2 -Ddebug=true -Dwerror=true -Dstrip=true -Db_pie=false -Db_coverage=false -Db_lto=false -Dcfi=false -Dtcg=enabled -Dxen=disabled -Dcapstone=disabled -Dfdt=auto -Dslirp=disabled -Dsdl=enabled -Dcocoa=disabled -Dprefix=/usr/local -Dbindir=/usr/local/bin -Ddatadir=/usr/local/share -Dincludedir=/usr/local/include -Dlibdir=/usr/local/lib -Dlibexecdir=/usr/local/libexec -Dlocaledir=/usr/local/share/locale -Dlocalstatedir=/usr/local/var -Dmandir=/usr/local/share/man -Dsysconfdir=/usr/local/etc '--native-file config-meson.cross'
Python system: Linux
The Meson build system
Version: 0.59.3
Source dir: /home/cornshiba/qemu
Build dir: /home/cornshiba/qemu/build
Build type: native build
Project name: qemu
Project version: 6.2.50
Sanity testing C compiler: cc -m64 -mcx16
Is cross compiler: False.
Sanity check compiler command line: cc -m64 -mcx16 sanitycheckc.c -o sanitycheckc.exe -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -lcrypto
Sanity check compile stdout:

-----
Sanity check compile stderr:

-----
Running test binary command: /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/sanitycheckc.exe
C compiler for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 (gcc 11.3.0 "cc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 ld.bfd 2.38
Sanity testing C compiler: cc -m64 -mcx16
Is cross compiler: False.
Sanity check compiler command line: cc -m64 -mcx16 sanitycheckc.c -o sanitycheckc.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
Sanity check compile stdout:

-----
Sanity check compile stderr:

-----
Running test binary command: /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/sanitycheckc.exe
C compiler for the build machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 (gcc 11.3.0 "cc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0")
C linker for the build machine: cc -m64 -mcx16 ld.bfd 2.38
Build machine cpu family: x86_64
Build machine cpu: x86_64
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Target machine cpu family: x86_64
Target machine cpu: x86_64
Program sh found: YES (/usr/bin/sh)
Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)
WARNING: Broken python installation detected. Python files installed by Meson might not be found by python interpreter.
Program bzip2 found: YES (/usr/bin/bzip2)
Sanity testing C++ compiler: c++ -m64 -mcx16
Is cross compiler: False.
Sanity check compiler command line: c++ -m64 -mcx16 sanitycheckcpp.cc -o sanitycheckcpp.exe -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -lcrypto
Sanity check compile stdout:

-----
Sanity check compile stderr:

-----
Running test binary command: /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/sanitycheckcpp.exe
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ -m64 -mcx16 (gcc 11.3.0 "c++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ -m64 -mcx16 ld.bfd 2.38
Program cgcc found: NO
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpdl2pk_x5
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpdl2pk_x5/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpdl2pk_x5/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -Wl,--start-group -lm -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 int main(void) { return 0; }

Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 
Library m found: YES
Run-time dependency threads found: YES
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp3bwaw34b
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp3bwaw34b/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp3bwaw34b/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -Wl,--start-group -lutil -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 int main(void) { return 0; }

Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 
Library util found: YES
Run-time dependency appleframeworks found: NO (tried framework)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is not cached.
Pkg-config binary for 1 specified from cross file, native file, or env var as ['pkg-config']
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
Determining dependency 'pixman-1' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion pixman-1` -> 0
0.40.0
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --cflags pixman-1` -> 0
-I/usr/include/pixman-1
env[PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS]: 1
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --libs pixman-1` -> 0
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpixman-1
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --libs pixman-1` -> 0
-lpixman-1
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpb1lf5wgc
Command line:  c++ -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpb1lf5wgc/testfile.cpp -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpb1lf5wgc/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -fpermissive -Wl,--start-group -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 #include<stdio.h>
        
        int main(void) {
            printf("%ld\n", (long)(sizeof(void *)));
            return 0;
        };
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 
Program stdout:

8

Program stderr:


Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpf2jf3_hr
Command line:  c++ -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpf2jf3_hr/testfile.cpp -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpf2jf3_hr/output.obj -c -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -fpermissive --print-search-dirs 

Code:
 
Compiler stdout:
 install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/

Compiler stderr:
 
Run-time dependency pixman-1 found: YES 0.40.0
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'zlib' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion zlib` -> 0
1.2.11
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --cflags zlib` -> 0

env[PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS]: 1
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --libs zlib` -> 0
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lz
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --libs zlib` -> 0
-lz
Run-time dependency zlib found: YES 1.2.11
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpybicbthu
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpybicbthu/testfile.c -E -P -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -P -O0 -std=gnu11 

Code:
 
        #ifdef __has_include
         #if !__has_include("libaio.h")
          #error "Header 'libaio.h' could not be found"
         #endif
        #else
         #include <libaio.h>
        #endif
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpybicbthu/testfile.c:4:12: error: #error "Header 'libaio.h' could not be found"
    4 |           #error "Header 'libaio.h' could not be found"
      |            ^~~~~

Has header "libaio.h" : NO 
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'liburing' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion liburing` -> 1

Run-time dependency liburing found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libxml-2.0' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0` -> 1

Run-time dependency libxml-2.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libnfs' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libnfs` -> 1

Run-time dependency libnfs found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpywncu5k_
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpywncu5k_/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpywncu5k_/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -std=gnu11 -Wl,--start-group -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 
  #include <stddef.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #ifdef CONFIG_LIBATTR
  #include <attr/xattr.h>
  #else
  #include <sys/xattr.h>
  #endif
  int main(void) { getxattr(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0); setxattr(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0); return 0; }
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 
Dependency appleframeworks (modules: Cocoa) skipped: feature cocoa disabled
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libseccomp' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libseccomp` -> 1

Run-time dependency libseccomp found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpqdg23cpo
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpqdg23cpo/testfile.c -E -P -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -P -O0 -std=gnu11 

Code:
 
        #ifdef __has_include
         #if !__has_include("cap-ng.h")
          #error "Header 'cap-ng.h' could not be found"
         #endif
        #else
         #include <cap-ng.h>
        #endif
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpqdg23cpo/testfile.c:4:12: error: #error "Header 'cap-ng.h' could not be found"
    4 |           #error "Header 'cap-ng.h' could not be found"
      |            ^~~~~

Has header "cap-ng.h" : NO 
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'xkbcommon' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion xkbcommon` -> 1

Run-time dependency xkbcommon found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpp7ba73jo
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpp7ba73jo/testfile.c -E -P -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -P -O0 -std=gnu11 

Code:
 
        #ifdef __has_include
         #if !__has_include("libvdeplug.h")
          #error "Header 'libvdeplug.h' could not be found"
         #endif
        #else
         #include <libvdeplug.h>
        #endif
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpp7ba73jo/testfile.c:4:12: error: #error "Header 'libvdeplug.h' could not be found"
    4 |           #error "Header 'libvdeplug.h' could not be found"
      |            ^~~~~

Has header "libvdeplug.h" : NO 
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libpulse' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libpulse` -> 1

Run-time dependency libpulse found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'alsa' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion alsa` -> 1

Run-time dependency alsa found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'jack' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion jack` -> 1

Run-time dependency jack found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'spice-protocol' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion spice-protocol` -> 1

Run-time dependency spice-protocol found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'spice-server' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion spice-server` -> 1

Run-time dependency spice-server found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpu53afmxp
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpu53afmxp/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpu53afmxp/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -Wl,--start-group -lrt -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 int main(void) { return 0; }

Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 
Library rt found: YES
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libiscsi' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libiscsi` -> 1

Run-time dependency libiscsi found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libzstd' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libzstd` -> 1

Run-time dependency libzstd found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'virglrenderer' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion virglrenderer` -> 1

Run-time dependency virglrenderer found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libcurl' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libcurl` -> 1

Run-time dependency libcurl found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'libudev' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion libudev` -> 1

Run-time dependency libudev found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpswpod9aq
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpswpod9aq/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpswpod9aq/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -Wl,--start-group -lmpathpersist -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 int main(void) { return 0; }

Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpathpersist: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpfclyn05t
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpfclyn05t/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpfclyn05t/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -Wl,--start-group -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 #include<stdio.h>
        
        int main(void) {
            printf("%ld\n", (long)(sizeof(void *)));
            return 0;
        };
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 
Program stdout:

8

Program stderr:


Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmphyy9nhef
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmphyy9nhef/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmphyy9nhef/output.obj -c -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 --print-search-dirs 

Code:
 
Compiler stdout:
 install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/

Compiler stderr:
 
Library mpathpersist found: NO
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'ncursesw' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion ncursesw` -> 1

Run-time dependency ncursesw found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpkib_je52
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpkib_je52/testfile.c -E -P -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -P -O0 -std=gnu11 -DNCURSES_WIDECHAR=1 

Code:
 
        #ifdef __has_include
         #if !__has_include("curses.h")
          #error "Header 'curses.h' could not be found"
         #endif
        #else
         #include <curses.h>
        #endif
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmpkib_je52/testfile.c:4:12: error: #error "Header 'curses.h' could not be found"
    4 |           #error "Header 'curses.h' could not be found"
      |            ^~~~~

Has header "curses.h" : NO 
Message: Trying with /usr/include/ncursesw
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp4hi28u2n
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/include/ncursesw -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp4hi28u2n/testfile.c -E -P -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -P -O0 -std=gnu11 -DNCURSES_WIDECHAR=1 

Code:
 
        #ifdef __has_include
         #if !__has_include("curses.h")
          #error "Header 'curses.h' could not be found"
         #endif
        #else
         #include <curses.h>
        #endif
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp4hi28u2n/testfile.c:4:12: error: #error "Header 'curses.h' could not be found"
    4 |           #error "Header 'curses.h' could not be found"
      |            ^~~~~

Has header "curses.h" : NO 
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp6lc3_z44
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp6lc3_z44/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp6lc3_z44/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -std=gnu11 -pthread -Wl,--start-group -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -liconv -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 
        #include <iconv.h>
        int main(void) {
          iconv_t conv = iconv_open("WCHAR_T", "UCS-2");
          return conv != (iconv_t) -1;
        }
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmph118tgbr
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmph118tgbr/testfile.c -o /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmph118tgbr/output.exe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O0 -std=gnu11 -pthread -Wl,--start-group -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group 

Code:
 
        #include <iconv.h>
        int main(void) {
          iconv_t conv = iconv_open("WCHAR_T", "UCS-2");
          return conv != (iconv_t) -1;
        }
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 
Running compile:
Working directory:  /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp1o210gy6
Command line:  cc -m64 -mcx16 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp1o210gy6/testfile.c -E -P -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -P -O0 -std=gnu11 

Code:
 
        #ifdef __has_include
         #if !__has_include("brlapi.h")
          #error "Header 'brlapi.h' could not be found"
         #endif
        #else
         #include <brlapi.h>
        #endif
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /home/cornshiba/qemu/build/meson-private/tmp1o210gy6/testfile.c:4:12: error: #error "Header 'brlapi.h' could not be found"
    4 |           #error "Header 'brlapi.h' could not be found"
      |            ^~~~~

Has header "brlapi.h" : NO 
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'sdl2' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion sdl2` -> 1

sdl2-config binary missing from cross or native file, or env var undefined.
Trying a default sdl2-config fallback at sdl2-config
sdl2-config found: NO
Run-time dependency sdl2 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and config-tool)

../meson.build:809:2: ERROR: Dependency "sdl2" not found, tried pkgconfig and config-tool
```

Comment: The instructions you linked are for MacOS.

Comment: `Called '/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion sdl2' -> 1` suggests your system is missing the sdl2 development package `libsdl2-dev`

Comment: We (AskUbuntu) have no obligation to debug some unsupported install script. Ask the people who provided the script.